# CentOS 6 - iptables preventing web access via port 80

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, iptables

I'm setting up a new web server with CentOS 6.2 and am not able to connect via the web. Everything looks set up correctly in `httpd.conf` and Apache is running, so I'm assuming it's an iptables issue.

Is there anything in the following which could be causing the issue?

EDIT: If i stop iptables, I can connect fine, so must be something needing tweaked in the below. I've already run `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` and saved and restarted iptables but made no difference

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Following advice in answer below:

```
[root@staging ~]# iptables -N TCP
[root@staging ~]# iptables -A TCP -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
[root@staging ~]# iptables-save > /etc/iptables/iptables.rules
-bash: /etc/iptables/iptables.rules: No such file or directory
[root@staging ~]# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Nov  8 14:09:09 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [91:7480]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [70:6556]
:TCP - [0:0]
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov  8 14:09:09 2012
[root@staging ~]# iptables-restore
^C
[root@staging ~]# service iptables start
iptables: Applying firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
```

Further edit: iptables-save showed nothing as I ran it after I'd stopped iptables! So here's the output:

```
# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Nov  8 14:39:10 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [28:3344]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov  8 14:39:10 2012
```

Comment: Aren't there any rules in the OUTPUT chain? Can you post the output of `iptables-save`?

Comment: Added the Output chain rule in, sorry missed that from original paste. No output from iptables-save

Comment: I'm quite surprised `iptables-save` doesn't show any output, this means there are no active rules? Can you execute `iptables --version`, `iptables -S`, `lsof -i | grep http` and `uname -a` and post it? I've set up `iptables` as described on a test computer running Apache and could access port 80, which makes sense, because rule 3 in the input chain accepts all traffic. Maybe the web server has more than one network card (or more than one IP address) and the forward chain comes into play?

Comment: And now, after following the advice in the answer below, does it work? And if it doesn't, if you stop `iptables` altogether, does it work again? And again a bit I'm missing, does the web server have more than one IP address (check it with `ip address` or `ifconfig`? The output of commands `iptables --version`, `iptables -S`, `lsof -i | grep http` and `uname -a` could also be helpful.

Comment: iptables-save does have output (posted above), i ran it after i'd stopped iptables which is why I got nothing, unsurprisingly. The web server has one IP, I can access it fine when iptables are stopped

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `iptables-save` output shows this bit of additional information for rule 3 not shown with `iptables -L`:

From `iptables -L` output one would think that **all** traffic is accepted:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

but `iptables-save` shows:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

which means that `iptables` indeed accepts all traffic... but only from the loopback interface (`lo`).

And that's the reason HTTP traffic never reaches your web server: The only traffic permitted is established connections in rule 1, ICMP (for example `ping`) in rule 2: `-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT` and SSH in rule 4: `-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`.

Then everything is rejected in rule 5: `-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited`.

That is, all HTTP traffic is rejected before even reaching rule 6: `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

**To correct** it delete rule 6 (`-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`):

```
iptables -D INPUT 6
```

and insert it (option `-I`) as rule 5:

```
iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

or import this:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.6 on Thu Nov  8 16:46:28 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [40:5423]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov  8 16:46:28 2012
```

by saving it into a file and executing `iptables-restore < file`.

EDIT: The OP noticed that the new rules are lost after restarting `iptables`.

As explained here: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables, any time we update the rules we need to save them, so run this:

```
# /sbin/service iptables save
```

to make changes permanent. Now the modified rules will be loaded by `iptables`.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed post and explanation. So this works (your example file had the `lo` line still above) - strangely though, if i stop iptables and restart, then the order reverts to the original setup.

Comment: The `lo` in the third rule is correct, otherwise all incoming ports are open, which largely defeats the purpose of using a firewall in the first place. As for `iptables` stubbornly reordering the rules: after modifying the rules run `/etc/init.d/iptables save` (I haven't used CentOS for ages but that's what I remember off the top of my head...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a master of iptables but the way mine is setup I used a separate custom chain for my port opening:

```
iptables -N TCP
iptables -A TCP -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Make sure you save

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/iptables.rules
```

To load

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/iptables.rules
```

^^ if the daemon doesn't load it for you.
I see that you said you already ran the method described above (just for the INPUT chain which I don't think matters) so that leaves me to believe that you might not be saving and reloading correctly. Is your iptables daemon running correctly?
Make sure the after running the above commands and using iptables -L you see the newly added chain and rule.

---

In response to your further trouble. iptables-save > location_of_rules I'm not sure where it  is on CentOS. But check to see if the new chain is there by using iptables -L

I also recommend checking to make sure that your website is not accessable. To do this go to your webbrowser (on the computer) and put in the url http: //127.0.0.1/ <-Without the sapce between : and //
If the website is accessible then the problem is with your router. You need to port-forward to open the port in your firewall. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

Comment: Followed your suggestions - although didn't specify iptables.rules file as doesn't exist in that location for me. Added the output to OP above.

Comment: but iptables -L still remains the same and your port remains closed?
have you tried "nmap" or a similar to to make sure the port is indeed closed. Other inaccessibility problems include routers which requires port forwarding.