# Apache test page not displaying

Tags: centos, apache-http-server

I have a virtual machine running CentOS 6.4, and trying to setup an Apache server, but I cannot get to display the Apache test page.

I've installed it using `yum install httpd` and checked that all my software is up-to-date.

I've then enabled name-based virtual hosting on port 80 by uncommenting the line `NameVirtualHost *:80` in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, and opened all incoming traffic in port 80:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/service iptables save
```

With all this setup, I then go into my browser in Windows and type the vitual machine's IP (192.168.1.XX), but the browser cannot connect to it.

On the other hand, when I run `curl localhost` in my virtual machine, I do see the HTML of the test page, so it might be that, for some reason, the firewall is still blocking port 80.

No virtual hosts have been added yet, but, as far as I know, that's not necessary to display the Apache test page.

---

Edit:

When running `netstat -ntlup`, it looks like httpd is running and has port 80 open:

```
[root@myhostname ~]# netstat -ntlup
Active Internet connections (only servers)
 Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1167/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1243/master
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      2245/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1167/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      1243/master
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               2087/dhclient
```

And the output of `apachectl -S` is:

```
[root@myhostname ~]# apachectl -S
httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for myhostname
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Tue Sep 17 17:03:06 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
VirtualHost configuration:
Syntax OK
```

If I add the line `ServerName myhostname:80` to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, then `apachectl` can determine the server's name (see below), but I still get no output in the Windows browser.

```
[root@myhostname ~]# apachectl -S
[Tue Sep 17 17:27:09 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
VirtualHost configuration:
Syntax OK
```

---

Any ideas on what might I be missing?

(I've moved this question here from [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18847924/2787045))

Comment: whats the output of 'netstat -ntlup' on the server as root? that will tell you if httpd is running and has tcp\80 bound (open).

Comment: Please add the output of `apachectl -S` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered already: 
[CentOS 6 - iptables preventing web access via port 80](https://superuser.com/questions/502723/centos-6-iptables-preventing-web-access-via-port-80)

The rules in iptables need to be rearranged instead of on the defaults set up by CentOS